# How to get sphere intersection points with P5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am using p5.js to create a [sphere](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/sphere)

What I am interested in is getting the points coordinates of the shapes used to modelize the sphere.

Is it possible to do so?

Basically, I would like to get the series of points used to draw the triangles that modelize the sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) (two angles and radius) to cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) conversion formula to compute points on a sphere:

[image: spherical to cartesian conversion formula]

(Image source: wikipedia)

If you think of the two angles as latitude(`lat`), longitude(`lon`) angles on our globe and a constant radius, in the JS you can look at this formula as:

```js
var x = radius * cos(lat) * sin(lon);
var y = radius * sin(lat) * sin(lon);
var z = radius * cos(lon);
```

Here's a basic sketch to illustrate the idea:

```js
var radius    = 120;
var latDetail = 0.243;
var lonDetail = 0.15;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300, WEBGL);
  strokeWeight(9);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  
  orbitControl();
  beginShape(POINTS);
  
  // iterate through lat, lon angles (in radians)
  for(var lat = 0; lat <= PI; lat += latDetail){
    for(var lon = 0; lon <= TWO_PI; lon += lonDetail){
      
      // for each sperical coordinate (lat, lon angles, radius)
      // convert to cartesian (x, y, z)
      
      var x = radius * cos(lat) * sin(lon);
      var y = radius * sin(lat) * sin(lon);
      var z = radius * cos(lon);
      // render each point
      vertex(x, y, z);
    }
  }
  
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Have a play with the `latDetail, lonDetail` variables which define how dense/sparse the sphere's parallels/meridians will be.

Having a quick look online for UV Spheres, [Daniel Sieger's Generating Spheres article](https://www.danielsieger.com/blog/2021/03/27/generating-spheres.html) is neat!

[image: 4 UV spheres with increasing U,V detail rendered with blue-ish gray flat shading and dark torquise outlines]

Even though the code is c++, the syntax is similar enough to understand:

```cpp
// generate vertices per stack / slice
  for (int i = 0; i < n_stacks - 1; i++)
  {
    auto phi = M_PI * double(i + 1) / double(n_stacks);
    for (int j = 0; j < n_slices; j++)
    {
      auto theta = 2.0 * M_PI * double(j) / double(n_slices);
      auto x = std::sin(phi) * std::cos(theta);
      auto y = std::cos(phi);
      auto z = std::sin(phi) * std::sin(theta);
      mesh.add_vertex(Point(x, y, z));
    }
  }
```

Pretty much the same formula (withouth the `radius` scalar) and a counter to for the number of segments on each angle (instead of an angle increment).

Here's a p5.js port:

```js
var radius    = 120;
var uSegments = 12;
var vSegments = 12;

// sliders
var uSegmentsSlider;
var vSegmentsSlider;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300, WEBGL);
  strokeWeight(9);
  uSegmentsSlider = createSlider(3, 36, 12, 1);
  vSegmentsSlider = createSlider(3, 36, 12, 1);
  uSegmentsSlider.position(10, 10);
  vSegmentsSlider.position(10, 30);
  createP('U').position(145, -3);
  createP('V').position(145, 17);
}

function draw() {
  // read slider values
  uSegments = uSegmentsSlider.value();
  vSegments = vSegmentsSlider.value();
  background(255);
  
  orbitControl();
  beginShape(POINTS);
  
  // iterate through u, v segments
  for(var u = 0; u < uSegments; u++){
    var phi = PI * (u + 1) / uSegments;
    for(var v = 0; v < vSegments; v++){
      var theta = TWO_PI * v / vSegments;
      // for each sperical coordinate (lat, lon angles, radius)
      // convert to cartesian (x, y, z)
      
      var x = radius * cos(theta) * sin(phi);
      var y = radius * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
      var z = radius * cos(phi);
      // render each point
      vertex(x, y, z);
    }
  }
  
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

**Update** Turns out [`p5.Vector.fromAngles()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/fromAngles) does this for you.

e.g.

```js
// iterate through u, v segments
  for(var u = 0; u < uSegments; u++){
    var phi = PI * (u + 1) / uSegments;
    for(var v = 0; v < vSegments; v++){
      var theta = TWO_PI * v / vSegments;
      // for each sperical coordinate (lat, lon angles, radius)
      // convert to cartesian (x, y, z)

      let p = p5.Vector.fromAngles(phi, theta, radius);
      // render each point
      vertex(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    }
  }
```

The above isn't great because it's allocating a new `p5.Vector` on each call (not recommended in `draw()`), but hopefully the idea is illustrated and you can pre-calculate the points in `setup()` then simply render in `draw()`