# Unable to set 2D Javascript array inside nested loop

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, p5.js

I am trying to convert a 2D grid of `(x, y)` points to a sphere in space. I loop through all of the points in the grid and set the value to an object `{x: someX, y: someY, z: someZ}`. But for some reason, the value I get inside the loop is different from the value outside. Do I have a typo or is this something about JS I don't understand yet? Here is the exact section causing issues:

```
for (let y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
    points[y][x] = grid2Sphere(x, y); //returns {x: someX, y: someY, z: someZ}. This works.
    console.log(points[y][x]);  // This logs the correct values
  }
  console.log(points[y]); // This is always equal to the row where y = 0. It's as if everything that happened in the inner loop did not get set.
}
```

For those interested, here is the entire file. I am using p5.js:

```
let R;
let points;
const GRID_WIDTH = 20;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  stroke("#000");
  R = 100;
  angleMode(RADIANS);
  points = new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill(new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill({}));
  
  // Calculate and draw each point.
  for (let y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
      points[y][x] = Object.assign({}, grid2Sphere(x, y));
      console.log(points[y][x]);
    }
    console.log(points[y]);
  }
  
  drawPoints(points);
}


function draw() {
  noLoop();
}

function drawPoints(pArray) {
  for (let y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
      let p = pArray[y][x];
      point(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    }
  }
}

function grid2Sphere(x, y) {
  var radX = map(x, 0, GRID_WIDTH - 1, -1 * PI * R, PI * R);
  var radY = map(y, 0, GRID_WIDTH - 1, -1 * PI / 2 * R, PI / 2 * R);
  var lon = radX / R;
  var lat = 2 * atan(exp(radY / R)) - PI / 2;
  var x_ = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon);
  var y_ = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon);
  var z_ = R * sin(lat);

  return {x: x_, y: y_, z: z_};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, the confusion stems from here actually:

```
points = new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill(new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill({}));
```

to break it down:

- `new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill({})` creates an array of empty objects
- `new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill(new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill({}));` makes a new array that is filled with **references** (not copies) of the first array (e.g. if the first array of `{},{},...` was called `myData`, the nested array would contain: `myData,myData,...` 20 times)

You could assign/allocate a new array on each y loop:

```js
// Calculate and draw each point.
  for (let y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++) {
    // ensure this is a new array (and not the same reference)
    points[y] = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
      points[y][x] = grid2Sphere(x, y);
      console.log(x, y, points[y][x]);
    }
    console.log(y, points[y]);
  }
```

Here's a modified version of your code:

```js
let R;
let points;
const GRID_WIDTH = 20;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  background(255);
  stroke("#000");
  R = 100;
  points = new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill(new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill({}));
  
  // Calculate and draw each point.
  for (let y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++) {
    // ensure this is a new array (and not the same reference)
    points[y] = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
      points[y][x] = grid2Sphere(x, y);
      console.log(x, y, points[y][x]);
    }
    console.log(y, points[y]);
  }
  
  // move camera for visual debugging purposes only
  camera(300, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  drawPoints(points);
}

function drawPoints(pArray) {
  for (let y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
      let p = pArray[y][x];
      point(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    }
  }
}

function grid2Sphere(x, y) {
  var radX = map(x, 0, GRID_WIDTH - 1, -1 * PI * R, PI * R);
  var radY = map(y, 0, GRID_WIDTH - 1, -1 * PI / 2 * R, PI / 2 * R);
  var lon = radX / R;
  var lat = 2 * atan(exp(radY / R)) - PI / 2;
  var x_ = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon);
  var y_ = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon);
  var z_ = R * sin(lat);

  return {x: x_, y: y_, z: z_};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

You could simplify further by just using an empty array that gets populated later (without worrying about filling it ahead of time):

```js
let R = 100;
let points;
const GRID_WIDTH = 20;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  background(255);
  stroke("#000");
  points = [];
  
  // Calculate and draw each point.
  for (let y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++) {
    points[y] = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
      points[y][x] = grid2Sphere(x, y);
      console.log(x, y, points[y][x]);
    }
    console.log(y, points[y]);
  }
  
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  orbitControl();
  drawPoints(points);
}

function drawPoints(pArray) {
  beginShape(POINTS);
  for (let y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
      let p = pArray[y][x];
      vertex(p.x, p.y, p.z);
    }
  }
  endShape();
}

function grid2Sphere(x, y) {
  var radX = map(x, 0, GRID_WIDTH - 1, -PI * R, PI * R);
  var radY = map(y, 0, GRID_WIDTH - 1, -HALF_PI * R, HALF_PI * R);
  var lon = radX / R;
  var lat = 2 * atan(exp(radY / R)) - PI / 2;
  
  return {
    x: R * cos(lat) * cos(lon),
    y: R * cos(lat) * sin(lon),
    z: R * sin(lat)
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

You can simplify even further by using a flat (1D) array (which you can easily set the size of if you need to):

```js
let R = 100;
const GRID_WIDTH = 20;
const NUM_POINTS = GRID_WIDTH * GRID_WIDTH; 
let points = new Array(NUM_POINTS);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  for(let i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++){
    let x = i % GRID_WIDTH;
    let y = i / GRID_WIDTH; // this is a float (ok for now, but with image indices floor() it)
    points[i] = p5.Vector.fromAngles(map(x, 0, GRID_WIDTH - 1, 0, PI), 
                                     map(y, 0, GRID_WIDTH - 1, 0, TWO_PI), 
                                     R);
  }
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  orbitControl();
  drawPoints(points);
}

function drawPoints(pArray) {
  beginShape(POINTS);
  pArray.forEach(p => vertex(p.x, p.y, p.z));
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Here, I'm also using `beginShape() / endShape() / vertex()` which should be more efficient than `point()` (though for your static image won't make a difference) and using [p5.Vector](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) which on top of providing `x,y,z` properties has a bunch of nice linear algebra utilities (e.g. computing angles between vectors, perpendiculars to vectors, etc.) as well as [p5.Vector.fromAngles()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/fromAngles) which does the spherical to cartesian coordinate conversion for you.

An even shorter version of the above (though less readible):

```js
let R = 100;
const GRID_WIDTH = 20;
let points = new Array(GRID_WIDTH * GRID_WIDTH).fill();

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  points.forEach((p,i) => points[i] = p5.Vector.fromAngles((i % GRID_WIDTH) / GRID_WIDTH * PI,
                                                           (i / GRID_WIDTH) / GRID_WIDTH * TWO_PI,                                                               R));
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  orbitControl();
  drawPoints(points);
}

function drawPoints(pArray) {
  beginShape(POINTS);
  pArray.forEach(p => vertex(p.x, p.y, p.z));
  endShape();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That was the most thorough and clear response to an answer I've had in a while. I'd upvote more if I could

Comment: It was a lucky coincidence I answered [a similar question a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455816/how-to-get-sphere-intersection-points-with-p5-js/71475396#71475396) (you might find the link to the c++ article there handy in terms of face indices, if you need that later on). This time around `p5.Vector.fromAngles()` caught my attention: very convenient. (You might like `p5.Vector.random3D().mult(R)` for a sphere with random points (not as grid) ([example](https://editor.p5js.org/george.profenza/sketches/TZmqXgVeJ)))

Comment: Nice answer. FYI you can omit `new` in front of `Array`. `.forEach((p,i) => points[i]...` seems clearer as `points = points.map(_, i) => p5.Vector...`, avoiding a mutation. Also, since the object in `.fill({})` is overwritten, maybe leave it out completely or use spread syntax, which doesn't have the aliasing gotcha. As you state in the next bullet, "`new Array(GRID_WIDTH).fill({})` creates an array of empty objects"` actually creates an array of one empty object referenced `GRID_WIDTH` times.